# Insert mysql datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I keep on having this error "Incorrect datetime value '2/1/16 7:22:00 AM'. I am sending a datetime value to a datetime data type column in mysql.

This is my code :

```
   String AMTime =(AMHour.Text + ':' + AMMinute.Text).ToString();

    am = Convert.ToDateTime(AMTime);
    // string am = AMTimeConvert.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    String NNTime = (NNHour.Text + ':' + NNHour.Text).ToString();

    nn = Convert.ToDateTime(NNTime);
   // string nn = NNTimeConvert.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    String PMTime = (PMHour.Text + ':' + PMMinute.Text).ToString();

    pm = Convert.ToDateTime(PMTime);
    // string pm = PMTimeConvert.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    if (Generic != null || Brand != null || ContainerNum != "" || status != "")
    {
        result = database.AddMedicinePrescription(PrescribedDays,Dosage,numprescribed,NumofIntake,am,nn,pm);
    }
```

This is the code that is to connect to my db

```
   public bool AddMedicinePrescription(int PrescribedDays, int Dosage, int numprescribed, int NumofIntake, DateTime am, DateTime nn, DateTime pm)
    {
        sqlstring = "INSERT INTO hdmedicinedispenser (PresDayOfIntake, PresNoOfMedicine, DosPerIntake, NumOfIntake,AMIntake, NNIntake, PMIntake)" + "VALUE (" + PrescribedDays + ", " + numprescribed + ", " + Dosage + ", " + NumofIntake + ", '"+ am +"', '"+ nn +"', '"+ pm +"' ) ";

        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstring, connect);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            connect.Close();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Warning 2: " + error.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? You may want to take a look on `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Comment: "Incorrect datetime value '2/1/16 7:22:00 AM' this is the error

Comment: I am asking *where* (as in: *which line*) does it occur.

Comment: am = Convert.ToDateTime(AMTime);

Comment: I see... then likely it is the query. Try to use Parameterized query: http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/ to avoid such unwanted errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you try to add your `DateTime` values as a character with single quotes like `'"+ am +"'`

You need to delete all single quotes for your `DateTime` values.

But more important, stop the string concatenation when you build your commands. You should *always* use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also you need `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of using a `MySqlDataAdapter` since `INSERT` statement does **not** return any data. It *just* inserts your value.

```
using(var connect = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = connect.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO hdmedicinedispenser (PresDayOfIntake, PresNoOfMedicine, DosPerIntake, NumOfIntake,AMIntake, NNIntake, PMIntake) 
                       VALUE (@PrescribedDays, @numprescribed, @Dosage, @NumofIntake, @am, @nn, @pm)";
   // Add your parameters with specify their types and size.
   connect.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Also you *might* need to read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)